# Tmux returns to home/prompt when scrolling on status bar changes

Tags: tmux, scrolling

When scrolling on tmux when using [powerline CPU system properties segment](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/configuration/segments/common.html#powerline.segments.common.sys.cpu_load_percent), every time the latter updates, the window goes back to the "home"/current prompt setting. This is really irritating since I want to see what I am scrolling up to, not be taken back to the prompt.

Is there was a way to stop tmux doing that?

I suspect any updating of the status bar will cause the problem, not just the powerline one. Thus I suspect there is a setting somewhere I could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tmux's own history (copy mode) is recommended instead of the terminal scrollback, because the terminal scrollback is not guaranteed to be complete or accurate when tmux is running.

However, if you want to use it anyway, tmux has no control over when your terminal chooses to scroll back to the bottom so you would be looking for an option in your terminal. ISTR some terminals do have one.

Alternatively, you can probably avoid or limit this by turning the status line off or by setting status-interval to 0 (you may possibly also need to also remove anything from the status line that is triggering an update itself).